# How to create and configure run.json in the new JetBrains Fleet for Nextjs?

Tags: javascript, next.js, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-fleet

I was trying how to create I / O for the new JetBrains' IDE called Fleet. But unfortunately couldn't do so. So, here I am asking the Stack Overflow community "How can I configure the run.json file in Fleet".

What am I supposed to write in that file?

I am trying to run next.js file in Fleet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Given, that this is a `Node.Js` application that has `package.json` file, you can navigate to `package.json` `scripts` block and run the coresponding command:

[image]